# fluent nhibernate Do both sides of a relationship need to be mapped?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Do both sides of a relationship need to be mapped?

Take the following class example where a parent can have many children, but the parent does not need any knowledge of the child

```
public class Parent{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

With the fluent mapping in child:

```
Map(x => x.ChildName).Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Parent, "Parent_id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is enough to have a foreign key from the child to the parent. The parent does not have to know its children in your class model. If you want more control from the parent side (i.e. delete the parent with all children in one shot), map the children as an inverse collection with cascade.

Comment: Without the mapping in the parent, is a deletion possible?

Comment: Yes, but have you have to delete all children (or set the Parent reference to null) manually first in order to delete the parent. Do that in one transaction and everything is fine.